# Executing "dotnet watch run" inside docker does not work (Error while killing process 'dotnet.exe run': The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

### Short story

Hey guys, running **"dotnet watch -v run"** inside docker does not work. After changing any file (so when application should be restarted), I get **'watch: Error while killing process'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe run': The system cannot find the file specified'.**

**Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?**

**How container is created** (see that I am using volume so when I update files inside WebDemo project they are updated in container)

```
docker image build -t test:test ./
docker container run --rm -it --name test --mount type=bind,source=E:\Projects\test\WebDemo,target=C:\src test:test
```

**Console output inside docker**

```
C:\src\WebDemo\WebDemo>dotnet watch -v run
watch : Polling file watcher is enabled
watch : Running MSBuild target 'GenerateWatchList' on 'C:\src\WebDemo\WebDemo\WebDemo.csproj'
watch : Started 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' with process id 980
watch : Process id 980 ran for 884ms
watch : Watching 5 file(s) for changes
watch : Started 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' with process id 1604
watch : Running dotnet with the following arguments: run
watch : Started
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\src\WebDemo\WebDemo

*HERE IS WHERE THE FILE WAS UPDATED*

watch : Killing process 1604
watch : Error while killing process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe run': The system cannot find the file specifi
ed.
```

### TL;DR;

- Below you can see I am currently using netcore 3.0 preview but I had the same issue with 2.2
- Note that reinstalling docker will not help (since I live in Windows world I took it to the next level and tried to reinstall the whole Windows :) - obviously it did not help)

**dotnet --info** (inside docker)

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100-preview7-012821
 Commit:    6348f1068a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview7-27912-14
  Commit:  4da6ee6450

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100-preview7-012821 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview7.19365.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview7-27912-14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0-preview7-27912-14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**docker info**

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 26
 Server Version: 19.03.1
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 18362 (18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.267)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.87GiB
 Name: DESKTOP-1OIN727
 ID: WBSQ:ILPO:MZCS:3YXS:MBHF:UHEX:APCV:EFNB:BN6K:OKRC:RNZW:54F3
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 28
  System Time: 2019-08-03T17:25:37.7173124+02:00
  EventsListeners: 1
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1903 AS sdk_layer
WORKDIR src/

COPY WebDemo/*.csproj WebDemo/
RUN dotnet restore ./WebDemo

COPY . ./
```

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the nanoserver image that the netcore SDK is based on does not contain `taskkill.exe`, which `dotnet watch` uses to kill the dotnet process before restarting it.

[I've logged this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1984) but unfortunately the only solution at this time is creating a custom netcore SDK image based on servercore.